# It gives null output when receive string list data from an activity

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-adapter

I have two String list to send to an activity from an adapter in android.

I have these two arrays in my adapter,

```
 private final List<String> toppingPriceTop;
 private final List<String> toppingDescriptionTop;
```

and in my adapter I have this button, this button click sending these details to the activity,

```
customize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent next = new Intent(context, ActivityCustomize.class);

                next.putExtra("description", descriptions.get(position));
                next.putExtra("imageUrl", imageUrls.get(position));

                next.putExtra("toppingDescriptionTop", toppingDescriptionTop.get(position));
                next.putExtra("toppingPriceTop", toppingPriceTop.get(position));

                context.startActivity(next);
                ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
```

In my activity I'm receiving these data as,

```
String [] toppingPriceTop = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("toppingPriceTop");
String [] toppingDescriptionTop = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("toppingDescriptionTop");
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");
String  description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
```

My problem is I'm getting values for imageUrl and description in the activity but for both the list arrays I'm getting null. an anyone tell me where I have gone wrong and how can I correct this please.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like

```
 next.putStringArrayListExtra("toppingDescriptionTop", toppingDescriptionTop);
 next.putStringArrayListExtra("toppingPriceTop", toppingPriceTop);
```

You Should pass all **List**

and get it like

```
List<String> toppingPriceTop = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("toppingPriceTop");
List<String> toppingDescriptionTop = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("toppingDescriptionTop");
```

### OR

do it like

```
 Bundle b=new Bundle();
 b.putStringArrayListExtra("toppingPriceTop ", toppingPriceTop);
 b.putStringArrayListExtra("toppingDescriptionTop", toppingDescriptionTop);
 next.putExtras(extras)
 context.startActivity(next);
```

and get it like:

```
 Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
 ArrayList<String> toppingPriceTop =b.getStringArrayList("toppingPriceTop");
 ArrayList<String> toppingDescriptionTop =b.getStringArrayList("toppingDescriptionTop");
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in my adapter, The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)